# Are hashes evenly distributed?

Tags: hash

Are all or any hash functions evenly distributed?

For example: if you had every combination of 256 bits and ran that through SHA256, would that produce approximately 1 of each combination, or would there be peaks?

Are distributions of the hashes calculable without going through the permutations in lower bit sizes?

Is evenness of the distribution of a hash function impacted by the length of the input vs the resultant hash length?

Which hashing functions are most evenly distributed?  (e.g. as close to 1 of each equal-bit-length combination possible)

Edit: The linked "duplicate" doesn't come close to addressing all these questions.

Comment: More duplicates: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2043, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/16440, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/33387, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44216, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67385

Comment: Can you clarify how this question is _different_ from all of the other related questions I linked?